# How to select all data from oracle database table in human readable format?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Sorry if my questions sounds silly, but I never worked with Oracle databases.

If I'm executing `select * from table` in MS Management Studio I have 3 options to select that data. I'm using grid and sometimes text. Using grid you're able to easily copy this into Excel spreadsheet.

When I'm selecting data from Oracle database table I have to format each column, but when I'm executing `select * from table`, I'm getting something very unreadable.

I'm using SQL Developer. Is there any way to retrieve data in more friendly view?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to investigate some other tool, such as [PL/SQL Developer](http://www.allroundautomations.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Run Statement` command (green arrow or Ctrl+Enter).
If you want export data, you can right click on table and select `Export..`

Answer (score 0):

First, SQL Developer allows you to export selected data into many format, including the "new" XLSX spreadsheet format. So you do not really need to worry about formatting.
But if you want to do it yourself, you can try to select the data in CSV format that is very easy to convert to Excel spreadsheet. Something like this:

```
SELECT '"' || column1 || '","' || column2 || '"'
FROM   table
WHERE  ...
```

You might want to convert dates to some universal format (like YYYY-MM-DD) and you need to enclose text with double quotes if they contain double quotes.

Comment: and if table contains 50 fields and there is 20 tables i have to review? I have to write 20 queries with coulumn1 ... column50 ???

Comment: For review, SQL Developer is perfect. You just browse the tables. Or you can export the data.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using Toad for Oracle, The free version gives you the option to view your data in Grid Format and you will also be able to export it out into Excel or csv.